How can I get the first weekly candle of the month in Pine Script?
I want a Function to return the nature of the first weekly candle of the month in Pine Script.
This code uses changes in the week of the year to determine the week of the month:
//@version=5
indicator("weekOfMonth()")
weekOfMonth(timestamp = time) =>
    var week = weekofyear(timestamp) %4
    if ta.change(weekofyear(timestamp))    
        week += 1
    if ta.change(month(timestamp))
        week := 1
    int result = timeframe.ismonthly ? na : week

plot(weekOfMonth())

How can I get the first weekly candle of the month in Pine Script?

You can do this with a flag. Reset it when it is a new month and look for a new week. Once it is a new week, set the flag and wait for next month.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var is_week_found = false

is_new_month = timeframe.change("M")
is_new_week = timeframe.change("W")

if (is_new_month)
    is_week_found := false  // Reset flag when it is a new month

is_first_week_candle = false

if (not is_week_found)
    if (is_new_week)
        is_first_week_candle := true
        is_week_found := true

bgcolor(is_first_week_candle ? color.new(color.red, 50) : na)



If so, how to know the nature of the first weekly candle of the month ?

What do you mean by "nature"?

I would like to know whether the nature of the bougie for the first week of the month is bearish or bullish

is_first_week_candle   is a flag for the first weekly candle. You can use that flag to see if it is a bullish or bearish candle.

Give me example code please
